# Jquery UI draggable wrong positioning relate parent container

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I have a problem with jquery-ui draggable. I have big one block inside parent container. Inside draggable block I have many images, which produce map image with pieces. Need to drag this images map inside parent `div` like we drag usually every maps.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="map_container">
                <div class="map_inner">
            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_01.gif" width="1228" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_02.gif" width="1229" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_03.gif" width="1228" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_04.gif" width="1229" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_05.gif" width="1228" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_06.gif" width="1229" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_07.gif" width="1228" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_08.gif" width="1229" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_09.gif" width="1228" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_10.gif" width="1229" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_11.gif" width="715" height="1228" alt="">



            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_12.gif" width="1229" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_13.gif" width="1229" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_14.gif" width="1228" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_15.gif" width="1229" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_16.gif" width="1229" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_17.gif" width="1228" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_18.gif" width="1229" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_19.gif" width="1229" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_20.gif" width="1228" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_21.gif" width="1229" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_22.gif" width="713" height="1228" alt="">



            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_23.gif" width="1229" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_24.gif" width="1229" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_25.gif" width="1228" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_26.gif" width="1229" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_27.gif" width="1229" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_28.gif" width="1228" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_29.gif" width="1229" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_30.gif" width="1229" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_31.gif" width="1228" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_32.gif" width="1229" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_33.gif" width="713" height="1229" alt="">



            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_34.gif" width="1229" height="1230" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_35.gif" width="1229" height="1230" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_36.gif" width="1228" height="1230" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_37.gif" width="1229" height="1230" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_38.gif" width="1229" height="1230" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_39.gif" width="1228" height="1230" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_40.gif" width="1229" height="1230" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_41.gif" width="1229" height="1230" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_42.gif" width="1228" height="1230" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_43.gif" width="1229" height="1230" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_44.gif" width="713" height="1230" alt="">
            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_45.gif" width="13000" height="26" alt="">


            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_46.gif" width="1229" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_47.gif" width="1229" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_48.gif" width="1228" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_49.gif" width="1229" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_50.gif" width="1229" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_51.gif" width="1228" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_52.gif" width="1229" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_53.gif" width="1229" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_54.gif" width="1228" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_55.gif" width="1229" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_56.gif" width="713" height="1229" alt="">


            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_57.gif" width="1229" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_58.gif" width="1229" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_59.gif" width="1228" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_60.gif" width="1229" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_61.gif" width="1229" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_62.gif" width="1228" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_63.gif" width="1229" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_64.gif" width="1229" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_65.gif" width="1228" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_66.gif" width="1229" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_67.gif" width="713" height="1228" alt="">


            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_68.gif" width="1229" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_69.gif" width="1229" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_70.gif" width="1228" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_71.gif" width="1229" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_72.gif" width="1229" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_73.gif" width="1228" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_74.gif" width="1229" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_75.gif" width="1229" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_76.gif" width="1228" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_77.gif" width="1229" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_78.gif" width="713" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_79.gif" width="1229" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_80.gif" width="1229" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_81.gif" width="1228" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_82.gif" width="1229" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_83.gif" width="1229" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_84.gif" width="1228" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_85.gif" width="1229" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_86.gif" width="1229" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_87.gif" width="1228" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_88.gif" width="1229" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_89.gif" width="713" height="1229" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_90.gif" width="1229" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_91.gif" width="1229" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_92.gif" width="1228" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_93.gif" width="1229" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_94.gif" width="1229" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_95.gif" width="1228" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_96.gif" width="1229" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_97.gif" width="1229" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_98.gif" width="1228" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_99.gif" width="1229" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_100.gif" width="713" height="1228" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_101.png" width="1229" height="1231" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_102.gif" width="1229" height="1231" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_103.gif" width="1228" height="1231" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_104.gif" width="1229" height="1231" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_105.gif" width="1229" height="1231" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_106.gif" width="1228" height="1231" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_107.gif" width="1229" height="1231" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_108.gif" width="1229" height="1231" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_109.gif" width="1228" height="1231" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_110.gif" width="1229" height="1231" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_111.jpg" width="713" height="1231" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/map_112.gif" width="13000" height="26" alt="">


            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/spacer.gif" width="1228" height="1" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/spacer.gif" width="1228" height="1" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/spacer.gif" width="1227" height="1" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/spacer.gif" width="1228" height="1" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/spacer.gif" width="1227" height="1" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/spacer.gif" width="2" height="1" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/spacer.gif" width="1227" height="1" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/spacer.gif" width="1227" height="1" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/spacer.gif" width="2" height="1" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/spacer.gif" width="1227" height="1" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/spacer.gif" width="2" height="1" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/spacer.gif" width="1226" height="1" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/spacer.gif" width="2" height="1" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/spacer.gif" width="1227" height="1" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/spacer.gif" width="2" height="1" alt="">

            <img class="lazy map_slice" src="http://pvdinvest.ru/wp-content/themes/businessx/images/map/spacer.gif" width="713" height="1" alt="">

                </div>
            </div>
```

And js

```
$('.map_inner').draggable({
    containment: '.map_container'
})
```

And css

```
.map_container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 900px;
}
.map_inner {

    position: absolute;
    width: 13000px;
    height: 12341px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

}
.map_inner img {
    float: left;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jkrqmsoy/

I you can't resolve my problem, please recommend me plugin to do that.

Comment: You will not want to use Draggable for this. I suspect you want to shift the position of the tiles based on the mouse movement. Draggable could be used to do this; you just need to build a single div that sits on top of all the tiles, and it's movement would adjust the position of the tiles.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Draggable, you will not want to *drag* the tiles or images. You will want to adjust the overall position based on the movement the user initiates.

Consider this HTML:

```
<div class="map_container">
  <div class="map_inner">
    <!-- Images -->
  </div>
  <div class="map_move_layer">
  </div>
</div>
```

If we used this CSS:

```
.map_move_layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

We can place a sort of invisible `div` on top of the tiles. We want tit to be the same size of your window or viewport.

```
$(".map_move_layer").css({
  width: $(window).width() + "px",
  height: $(window).height() + "px"
});
```

We would want then apply draggable to this element and adjust the position of the `map_inner` based on that movement.

Test Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/xwkddzec/8/

**JavaScript Snippet**

```
$(function() {
  var max = {
    top: 12341,
    left: 13000
  };
  var min = {
    top: -12341,
    left: -13000
  }

  $(".map_move_layer").css({
    width: $(window).width() + "px",
    height: $(window).height() + "px"
  }).draggable({
    drag: function(e, ui) {
      var p = ui.position;
      var mPos = $(".map_inner").position();
      var newPos = {
        top: mPos.top + p.top,
        left: mPos.left + p.left
      };
      if ((newPos.top < max.top && newPos.top > min.top) || (newPos.left < max.left && newPos.left > min.left)) {
        $(".map_inner").css({
          top: newPos.top + "px",
          left: newPos.left + "px"
        });
      }
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      $(this).css({
        top: 0,
        left: 0
      });
    }
  });
});
```

When the user clicks and drags, it will re-position the map area. When they stop, the overlay is return to it's start position. You can adjust this as needed so the movement is less or more. Example:

```
newPos = {
  top: mPos.top + (p.top * .5),
  left: mPos.left + (p.left * .5)
}
```

Hope this helps.

Forked from your code Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/wees27gt/

Comment: Hi! Thank's for reply. But this solution not work properly as needed. First - if i click on map and drag slowly in some destination - map start to "swim" out of screen, and seems to containment not work at all, because i can drag map out of parent div..